# SQL Monitor for Delphi 5/400 - BDE component

Tags: sql, delphi, bde

I have problem with delphi application which is running on database using BDE components. Application with GUI shows results but do not show SQL which is generated to get information from database. I need to find some of the results in tables, but I do not know data structure of the DB and I have no idea in which table I should look in. Any ideas how to extract that SQL that is generated from application as query to DB?

Comment: You are really still using BDE ?, it has been deprecated for decades. If you are writting a new project, switch to FireDAC and you will find tracing and monitor components by default (TFDMonitorFlatFileClientLink).

Comment: Yep its very big and old project. Can`t switch it. It is not up to me to change it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with these components :-(

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you thought about migrating the entire project to more modern components, like dbExpress ?. You have components collections that mimic BDE so the changes to your project would be minimal (and you would have the TSQLMonitor to trace your SQL commands).  http://www.ethea.it/eng_instantbdexpress.asp Migrating to FireDAC is also relatively easy. https://delphiparser.com/product/bde-to-firedac-free-migration-tool/ It will save you headaches in the future.

Comment: You mention "400" in your title: are you referring to the IBM AS/400?  Istr there was a SqlLink driver or similar available for it.

Comment: It's probably possible to hook the BDE dlls in order to get the SQL-Strings passed to them, but I must admit I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Have you seen this article, and do you have the Sql Monitor tool it mentions:http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/bdetoolsforworkingwiththebde_xml.html

Comment: @MartynA yes thats true, we are using AS/400. And thanks for that link - but cant find that tool mentioned in this document so I cant say it is the same sql monitor or it is not.